# How to webscrape MLB WAR using python?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the MLB pitcher's WAR.

Here is the error:

IndexError: list index out of range

The code worked great for names, age and games, however, I ran into an error when adding WAR_pitch.

```
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    from lxml.html import fromstring

    import pandas as pd

    url = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2019-value- 
    pitching.shtml  "

    content = str(urlopen(url).read())
    comment = content.replace("-->","").replace("<!--","")
    tree = fromstring(comment)

    columns1 = ("names", "age", "games", "war")
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns1)

    for idx, pitcher_row in enumerate(tree.xpath('//table[contains(@class,"stats_table")]//tr[contains(@class,"full_table")]')):
        names = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="player"]/a')[0].text
        age = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="age"]/text()')[0]
        games = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="G"]/text()')[0]
        war = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="WAR_pitch"]/text()')[0]


        df1.loc[idx] = (names, age, games, war)
        print(names, age, games, war)
```

## The last name that prints before the error is Jason Vargas.

Here is an example of the printout (names, age, games, war):

```
Jason Vargas 36 14 1.3
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time! =)

Comment: Provide a url to the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `selenium` with `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
d.get('https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2019-value-pitching.shtml')
page = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').find('table', {'id':'players_value_pitching'})
h, data = [i.text for i in page.find_all('th')], [[b.find('th').text, *[i.text.replace('\xa0', ' ') for i in b.find_all('td')]] for b in page.find_all('tr')[1:]]
final_data = [dict(zip(h, i)) for i in data]
```

---

To get WAR, you can look up the desired value in the dictionary for each player:

```
wars = [[i['Name'], i['WAR']] for i in final_data if 'Name' in i]
```

Output:

```
[['Austin Adams', '0.1'], ['Austin Adams', '0.8'], ['Chance Adams', '-0.2'], ['Dario Agrazal', '0.3'], ['R.J. Alaniz', '-0.4'], ['Matt Albers', '0.5'], ['Hanser Alberto', '-0.1'], ['Sandy Alcantara', '0.8'], ['Victor Alcantara', '0.4'], ['Scott Alexander*', '0.2'], ['Cody Allen', '-0.2'], ['Logan Allen*', '0.2'], ['Yency Almonte', '0.3'], ['Dan Altavilla', '-0.2'], ['Aaron Altherr', '0.0'], ['Jose Alvarado*', '0.5'], ['Jose Alvarez*', '0.2'], ['Adbert Alzolay', '-0.2'], ['Brett Anderson*', '1.5'], ['Chase Anderson', '0.4'], ['Cody Anderson', '-0.6'], ['Drew Anderson', '-0.1'], ['Justin Anderson', '0.3'], ['Nick Anderson', '0.1'], ['Shaun Anderson', '0.4'], ['Tanner Anderson', '-0.2'], ['Tyler Anderson*', '-0.8'], ['Matt Andriese', '-0.5'], ['Victor Arano', '0.1'], ['Pedro Araujo', '-0.1'], ['Chris Archer', '0.2'], ['Rogelio Armenteros', '0.1'], ['Shawn Armstrong', '0.1'], ['Jake Arrieta', '1.4'], ['Pedro Avila', '0.3'], ['Luis Avilan*', '-0.3'], ['Pedro Baez', '0.0'], ['Sandy Baez', '0.0'], ['Homer Bailey', '0.6'], ['Manny Banuelos*', '-0.4'], ['Luke Bard', '-0.2'], ['Scott Barlow', '-0.6'], ['Jacob Barnes', '-0.4'], ['Matt Barnes', '0.1'], ['Tony Barnette', '0.0'], ['Kyle Barraclough', '-0.5'], ['Jake Barrett', '-0.2'], ['Jaime Barria', '0.1'], ['Tyler Bashlor', '0.0'], ['Anthony Bass', '0.5'], ['Chris Bassitt', '1.1'], ['Trevor Bauer', '1.9'], ['Gerson Bautista', '-0.2'], ['Cam Bedrosian', '0.6'], ['Tyler Beede', '-0.6'], ['Jalen Beeks*', '1.3'], ['Travis Bergen*', '0.1'], ['Jose Berrios', '2.0'], ['Chad Bettis', '0.2'], ['Joe Biagini', '0.7'], ['Jesse Biddle*', '-0.8'], ['Shane Bieber', '2.2'], ['Kyle Bird*', '-0.1'], ['Ty Blach*', '-0.3'], ['Paul Blackburn', '-0.2'], ['Richard Bleier*', '-0.2'], ['Jerry Blevins*', '0.0'], ['James Bourque', '-0.1'], ['Matt Bowman', '0.4'], ['Brad Boxberger', '-0.1'], ['Matthew Boyd*', '2.9'], ['Brad Brach', '-0.3'], ['Chasen Bradford', '0.1'], ['Archie Bradley', '-0.4'], ['Ryan Brasier', '0.7'], ['Steven Brault*', '0.9'], ['John Brebbia', '0.4'], ['Brandon Brennan', '-0.1'], ['Colten Brewer', '0.4'], ['Austin Brice', '0.7'], ['Jeff Brigham', '-0.2'], ['Zack Britton*', '1.1'], ['Aaron Brooks', '0.1'], ['Clay Buchholz', '-0.1'], ['Ryan Buchter*', '0.3'], ['Walker Buehler', '1.1'], ['Madison Bumgarner*', '0.7'], ['Aaron Bummer*', '1.3'], ['Dylan Bundy', '1.1'], ['Nick Burdi', '-0.5'], ['Corbin Burnes', '-1.8'], ['Ryan Burr', '0.0'], ['Ty Buttrey', '1.5'], ['Genesis Cabrera*', '-0.4'], ['Trevor Cahill', '-0.5'], ['Griffin Canning', '1.5'], ['Matt Carasiti', '0.1'], ['Victor Caratini', '0.0'], ['Shane Carle', '-0.4'], ['David Carpenter', '-0.1'], ['Ryan Carpenter*', '-0.9'], ['Carlos Carrasco', '0.6'], ['Andrew Cashner', '2.3'], ['Diego Castillo', '-0.2'], ['Luis Castillo', '3.4'], ['Miguel Castro', '0.1'], ['Xavier Cedeno*', '0.1'], ['Luis Cessa', '0.1'], ['Jhoulys Chacin', '-0.2'], ['Andrew Chafin*', '0.6'], ['Aroldis Chapman*', '1.2'], ['JT Chargois', '0.0'], ['Tyler Chatwood', '0.4'], ['Jesse Chavez', '1.8'], ['Wei-Yin Chen*', '-1.1'], ['Yonny Chirinos', '2.1'], ['Adam Cimber', '0.5'], ['Steve Cishek', '1.1'], ['Jose Cisnero', '0.1'], ['Aaron Civale', '0.3'], ['Taylor Clarke', '-0.4'], ['Alex Claudio*', '0.1'], ['Mike Clevinger', '0.0'], ['Tyler Clippard', '0.4'], ['Alex Cobb', '-0.5'], ['A.J. Cole', '-0.2'], ['Gerrit Cole', '2.1'], ['Taylor Cole', '0.0'], ['Tim Collins*', '0.1'], ['Alex Colome', '1.5'], ['Adam Conley*', '-1.2'], ['Sam Coonrod', '0.0'], ['Patrick Corbin*', '2.5'], ['Jimmy Cordero', '0.0'], ['Nestor Cortes Jr.*', '0.1'], ['Dylan Covey', '0.5'], ['Stefan Crichton', '0.1'], ['Kyle Crick', '0.9'], ['Charlie Culberson', '0.0'], ['John Curtiss', '0.0'], ['Yu Darvish', '0.6'], ['Zach Davies', '1.5'], ['Austin Davis*', '0.1'], ['Chris Davis', '0.0'], ['Rookie Davis', '-0.1'], ['Wade Davis', '0.2'], ['Grant Dayton*', '0.2'], ['Chase De Jong', '-0.1'], ['Enyel De Los Santos', '-0.2'], ['Jacob deGrom', '2.8'], ['Daniel Descalso', '-0.1'], ['Anthony DeSclafani', '1.1'], ['Odrisamer Despaigne', '-0.3'], ['Ross Detwiler*', '0.2'], ['Chris Devenski', '0.1'], ['Edwin Diaz', '0.0'], ['Jairo Diaz', '0.3'], ['Miguel Diaz', '-0.1'], ['Phillip Diehl*', '-0.1'], ['Jake Diekman*', '0.2'], ['Brandon Dixon', '-0.1'], ['Seranthony Dominguez', '0.1'], ['Sean Doolittle*', '1.2'], ['Kyle Dowdy', '-0.4'], ['Oliver Drake', '0.4'], ['Tyler Duffey', '0.0'], ['Danny Duffy*', '0.7'], ['Zach Duke*', '0.1'], ['Ryan Dull', '-0.5'], ['Mike Dunn*', '-0.2'], ['Jon Duplantier', '0.3'], ['Montana DuRapau', '-0.5'], ['Sam Dyson', '0.7'], ['Ryan Eades', '0.1'], ['Carl Edwards Jr.', '-0.2'], ['Jon Edwards', '0.2'], ['Zach Eflin', '2.4'], ['Jerad Eickhoff', '0.2'], ['Roenis Elias*', '0.4'], ['Chris Ellis', '0.0'], ['Nathan Eovaldi', '0.0'], ['Robbie Erlin*', '-0.3'], ['Tom Eshelman', '0.2'], ['Carlos Estevez', '0.4'], ['Marco Estrada', '-0.4'], ['Peter Fairbanks', '-0.1'], ['Jeurys Familia', '-1.0'], ['Jake Faria', '0.2'], ['Buck Farmer', '0.4'], ['Erick Fedde', '1.1'], ['Ryan Feierabend*', '-0.2'], ['Michael Feliz', '-0.2'], ['Caleb Ferguson*', '-0.3'], ['Jose Fernandez*', '-0.4'], ['Matt Festa', '0.2'], ['Mike Fiers', '1.5'], ['Heath Fillmyer', '-0.4'], ['Jack Flaherty', '0.6'], ['Chris Flexen', '-0.4'], ['Dylan Floro', '-0.5'], ['Brian Flynn*', '0.4'], ['Mike Foltynewicz', '-0.7'], ['Wilmer Font', '0.2'], ['Ty France', '0.0'], ['Caleb Frare*', '-0.1'], ['Kyle Freeland*', '-0.5'], ['Mike Freeman', '0.0'], ['Sam Freeman*', '0.0'], ['Max Fried*', '1.6'], ['Jace Fry*', '-0.3'], ['Paul Fry*', '0.2'], ['Carson Fulmer', '-0.3'], ['Drew Gagnon', '-0.6'], ['Giovanny Gallegos', '0.9'], ['Zac Gallen', '0.2'], ['John Gant', '1.5'], ['Edgar Garcia', '-0.1'], ['Jarlin Garcia*', '0.3'], ['Luis Garcia', '0.4'], ['Yimi Garcia', '0.0'], ['Amir Garrett*', '1.8'], ['Reed Garrett', '-0.3'], ['Ryan Garton', '-0.1'], ['Kevin Gausman', '-0.8'], ['Sam Gaviglio', '0.5'], ['Cory Gearrin', '0.4'], ['Domingo German', '1.0'], ['Kyle Gibson', '0.4'], ['Ken Giles', '1.6'], ['Sean Gilmartin*', '-0.2'], ['Lucas Giolito', '3.7'], ['Mychal Givens', '0.0'], ['Tyler Glasnow', '1.8'], ['Zack Godley', '-1.0'], ['Jeanmar Gomez', '-0.3'], ['Tony Gonsolin', '-0.3'], ['Marco Gonzales*', '1.1'], ['Chi Chi Gonzalez', '0.1'], ['Gio Gonzalez*', '0.8'], ['Nick Goody', '0.2'], ['Trevor Gott', '0.3'], ['Matt Grace*', '-0.3'], ['Jon Gray', '3.3'], ['Sonny Gray', '1.5'], ['Chad Green', '-0.4'], ['Shane Greene', '1.5'], ['Luke Gregerson', '-0.1'], ['Zack Greinke', '3.3'], ['Robert Gsellman', '-0.3'], ['Reymin Guduan*', '-0.4'], ['Javy Guerra', '0.5'], ['Junior Guerra', '0.4'], ['Tayron Guerrero', '0.0'], ['Jedd Gyorko', '0.0'], ['Josh Hader*', '2.0'], ['David Hale', '0.5'], ['Cole Hamels*', '3.2'], ['J.D. Hammer', '0.2'], ['Brad Hand*', '1.4'], ['J.A. Happ*', '0.5'], ['Blaine Hardy*', '0.4'], ['Ryne Harper', '0.6'], ['Will Harris', '1.2'], ['Donnie Hart*', '0.3'], ['Geoff Hartlieb', '-0.4'], ['Joe Harvey', '0.0'], ['Matt Harvey', '-0.8'], ['Andrew Heaney*', '0.2'], ['Taylor Hearn*', '-0.3'], ['Jeremy Hellickson', '-0.2'], ['Ryan Helsley', '0.1'], ['Heath Hembree', '0.7'], ['Kyle Hendricks', '1.7'], ['Liam Hendriks', '1.9'], ['Darwinzon Hernandez*', '-0.1'], ['David Hernandez', '-0.2'], ['Elieser Hernandez', '0.2'], ['Felix Hernandez', '-0.3'], ['Kelvin Herrera', '-0.6'], ['David Hess', '-0.8'], ['Jordan Hicks', '0.6'], ['Trevor Hildenberger', '-1.0'], ['Rich Hill*', '0.9'], ['Tim Hill*', '-0.1'], ['Yoshihisa Hirano', '-0.3'], ['Jeff Hoffman', '0.1'], ['Jonathan Holder', '-1.1'], ['Derek Holland*', '-0.8'], ['Greg Holland', '1.0'], ['Clay Holmes', '0.0'], ['Adrian Houser', '0.6'], ['Wei-Chieh Huang', '-0.1'], ['Dakota Hudson', '0.4'], ['Daniel Hudson', '0.9'], ['Jared Hughes', '0.7'], ['Tommy Hunter', '0.1'], ['Raisel Iglesias', '0.3'], ['Cole Irvin*', '-0.6'], ['Edwin Jackson', '-1.6'], ['Jay Jackson', '-0.2'], ['Luke Jackson', '0.9'], ['Josh James', '0.1'], ['Kenley Jansen', '0.2'], ['Jeremy Jeffress', '0.2'], ['Dan Jennings*', '-0.4'], ['Williams Jerez*', '0.0'], ['Jake Jewell', '-0.3'], ['Eduardo Jimenez', '-0.1'], ['Joe Jimenez', '-0.2'], ['Brian Johnson*', '-0.2'], ['DJ Johnson', '-0.4'], ['Nate Jones', '0.2'], ['Caleb Joseph', '0.0'], ['Jakob Junis', '0.1'], ['Ariel Jurado', '0.9'], ['Tommy Kahnle', '0.4'], ['Nate Karns', '0.3'], ['Keone Kela', '0.1'], ['Brad Keller', '1.0'], ['Mitch Keller', '-0.6'], ['Shawn Kelley', '1.6'], ['Joe Kelly', '-0.9'], ['Merrill Kelly', '1.3'], ['Ian Kennedy', '0.7'], ['Clayton Kershaw*', '1.4'], ['Dallas Keuchel*', '0.0'], ['Yusei Kikuchi*', '0.4'], ['Craig Kimbrel', '-0.2'], ['Nick Kingham', '-1.5'], ['Tyler Kinley', '-0.1'], ['Brandon Kintzler', '1.4'], ['Andrew Kittredge', '0.3'], ['Branden Kline', '-0.3'], ['Corey Kluber', '-0.4'], ['Matt Koch', '-0.6'], ['Adam Kolarek*', '0.2'], ['Travis Lakins', '-0.1'], ['Peter Lambert', '0.2'], ['Eric Lauer*', '0.7'], ['Derek Law', '-0.5'], ['Mike Leake', '1.5'], ['Wade LeBlanc*', '0.5'], ['Jose Leclerc', '0.5'], ['Dominic Leone', '-0.4'], ['Jon Lester*', '1.1'], ['Francisco Liriano*', '1.3'], ['Zack Littell', '-0.3'], ['Ben Lively', '-0.1'], ['Jonathan Loaisiga', '0.2'], ['Walker Lockett', '-0.4'], ['Jorge Lopez', '-0.6'], ['Pablo Lopez', '0.8'], ['Reynaldo Lopez', '-0.2'], ['Yoan Lopez', '1.4'], ['Michael Lorenzen', '0.5'], ['Aaron Loup*', '0.2'], ['Richard Lovelady*', '0.1'], ['Josh Lucas', '0.0'], ['Joey Lucchesi*', '1.0'], ['Elvis Luciano', '-0.1'], ['Seth Lugo', '0.3'], ['Jordan Lyles', '1.7'], ['Lance Lynn', '3.4'], ['Tyler Lyons*', '-0.4'], ['Kenta Maeda', '1.0'], ['Matt Magill', '0.0'], ['Tyler Mahle', '1.2'], ['Luke Maile', '0.1'], ['Dillon Maples', '0.1'], ['Nick Margevicius*', '-0.8'], ['Parker Markel', '-0.2'], ['German Marquez', '3.3'], ['Evan Marshall', '0.4'], ['Brett Martin*', '0.5'], ['Chris Martin', '1.0'], ['Corbin Martin', '-0.3'], ['Russell Martin', '0.1'], ['Carlos Martinez', '0.4'], ['Jeff Mathis', '0.0'], ['Phil Maton', '-0.6'], ['Steven Matz*', '0.3'], ['Trevor May', '0.3'], ['Mike Mayers', '0.0'], ['Tim Mayza*', '0.2'], ['Chris Mazza', '0.2'], ['Kevin McCarthy', '0.1'], ['T.J. McFarland*', '-0.7'], ['Jake McGee*', '0.9'], ['Kyle McGowin', '-0.3'], ['Collin McHugh', '-0.1'], ['Brendan McKay*', '0.4'], ['David McKay', '0.1'], ['Alex McRae', '-0.6'], ['John Means*', '3.2'], ['Adalberto Mejia*', '-0.6'], ['Mark Melancon', '0.2'], ['Daniel Mengden', '0.4'], ['Miles Mikolas', '0.9'], ['Wade Miley*', '2.1'], ['Andrew Miller*', '-0.2'], ['Justin Miller', '0.3'], ['Shelby Miller', '-1.1'], ['Tommy Milone*', '1.5'], ['Juan Minaya', '0.5'], ['Mike Minor*', '5.7'], ['A.J. Minter*', '-0.7'], ['Frankie Montas', '2.1'], ['Mike Montgomery*', '-0.4'], ['Andrew Moore', '-0.1'], ['Dylan Moore', '-0.1'], ['Matt Moore*', '0.7'], ['Kendrys Morales', '0.0'], ['Adam Morgan*', '0.2'], ['Mike Morin', '0.3'], ['Reyes Moronta', '1.0'], ['Charlie Morton', '3.1'], ['John Ryan Murphy', '-0.3'], ['Tom Murphy', '0.0'], ['Harrison Musgrave*', '0.3'], ['Joe Musgrove', '1.0'], ['Jimmy Nelson', '-0.5'], ['Hector Neris', '0.9'], ['Pat Neshek', '-0.1'], ['Dovydas Neverauskas', '-0.2'], ['Jake Newberry', '0.1'], ['Sean Newcomb*', '0.9'], ['Juan Nicasio', '0.1'], ['Stephen Nogosek', '-0.1'], ['Aaron Nola', '1.6'], ['Daniel Norris*', '1.3'], ['James Norwood', '0.1'], ['Ivan Nova', '0.0'], ['Eduardo Nunez', '0.0'], ["Ryan O'Rourke*", '0.1'], ['Scott Oberg', '2.3'], ['Jake Odorizzi', '2.3'], ['Seunghwan Oh', '-0.6'], ['Tyler Olson*', '0.3'], ['Luis Ortiz', '-0.1'], ['Josh Osich*', '0.1'], ['Roberto Osuna', '1.1'], ['Corey Oswalt', '-0.4'], ['Dan Otero', '0.1'], ['Adam Ottavino', '1.8'], ['Chris Owings', '-0.1'], ['Chris Paddack', '1.5'], ['Emilio Pagan', '1.5'], ['Joe Palumbo*', '-0.4'], ['Thomas Pannone*', '-0.1'], ['Blake Parker', '0.0'], ['Wes Parsons', '0.2'], ['James Paxton*', '0.6'], ['Brad Peacock', '1.1'], ['Felix Pena', '0.6'], ['Freddy Peralta', '-0.4'], ['Wandy Peralta*', '-0.2'], ['Wily Peralta', '0.0'], ['Luis Perdomo', '0.8'], ['Cionel Perez*', '-0.7'], ['Hernan Perez', '0.1'], ['Martin Perez*', '0.2'], ['Oliver Perez*', '0.5'], ['Dillon Peters*', '0.2'], ['Tim Peterson', '0.0'], ['Yusmeiro Petit', '1.4'], ['Jake Petricka', '0.1'], ['David Phelps', '0.2'], ['Evan Phillips', '-0.3'], ['Michael Pineda', '0.2'], ['Nick Pivetta', '0.3'], ['Kevin Plawecki', '0.1'], ['Zach Plesac', '1.0'], ['Adam Plutko', '0.1'], ['Colin Poche*', '0.3'], ['Drew Pomeranz*', '-0.8'], ['Daniel Ponce de Leon', '0.6'], ['Sean Poppen', '-0.1'], ['Rick Porcello', '0.4'], ['Brooks Pounders', '0.0'], ['Bobby Poyner*', '-0.4'], ['Ryan Pressly', '1.5'], ['David Price*', '1.9'], ['Austin Pruitt', '-0.1'], ['Cal Quantrill', '0.4'], ['Jose Quijada*', '0.1'], ['Jose Quintana*', '1.1'], ['Tanner Rainey', '-0.1'], ['Erasmo Ramirez', '-0.1'], ['Neil Ramirez', '-0.1'], ['Nick Ramirez*', '0.4'], ['Noe Ramirez', '0.8'], ['Yefry Ramirez', '-0.2'], ['Edubray Ramos', '0.1'], ['Matt Ramsey', '0.0'], ['Robbie Ray*', '0.9'], ['Cody Reed*', '0.2'], ['Sean Reid-Foley', '-0.1'], ['Zac Reininger', '-0.3'], ['Alex Reyes', '-0.4'], ['Gerardo Reyes', '-0.9'], ['Jacob Rhame', '0.0'], ['Clayton Richard*', '-0.1'], ['Trevor Richards', '1.1'], ['Yacksel Rios', '-0.1'], ['Tanner Roark', '2.1'], ['Daniel Robertson', '0.0'], ['David Robertson', '0.0'], ['Hansel Robles', '1.0'], ['Brady Rodgers', '-0.3'], ['Fernando Rodney', '-0.4'], ['Carlos Rodon*', '0.1'], ['Dereck Rodriguez', '-0.6'], ['Eduardo Rodriguez*', '1.1'], ['Jefry Rodriguez', '0.4'], ['Richard Rodriguez', '0.3'], ['Sean Rodriguez', '0.0'], ['Chaz Roe', '-0.1'], ['Josh Rogers*', '-0.2'], ['Taylor Rogers*', '1.3'], ['Jordan Romano', '0.0'], ['Fernando Romero', '-0.1'], ['Sergio Romo', '-0.3'], ['Hector Rondon', '0.7'], ['Jose Rondon', '0.0'], ['Randy Rosario*', '-0.2'], ['Trevor Rosenthal', '-1.0'], ['Joe Ross', '-0.9'], ['Tyson Ross', '-0.2'], ['Zac Rosscup*', '-0.2'], ['Jose Ruiz', '-0.1'], ['Nick Rumbelow', '-0.3'], ['Chris Rusin*', '-0.2'], ['Kyle Ryan*', '0.5'], ['Hyun-Jin Ryu*', '3.2'], ['CC Sabathia*', '0.9'], ['Casey Sadler', '0.4'], ['Connor Sadzeck', '0.4'], ['Fernando Salas', '0.0'], ['Chris Sale*', '1.8'], ['Jeff Samardzija', '0.1'], ['Adrian Sampson', '2.5'], ['Aaron Sanchez', '-0.6'], ['Anibal Sanchez', '2.0'], ['Pablo Sandoval', '0.0'], ['Dennis Santana', '-0.1'], ['Ervin Santana', '-0.4'], ['Hector Santiago*', '-0.1'], ['Josh Sborz', '-0.1'], ['Max Scherzer', '5.1'], ['Brian Schlitter', '0.0'], ['Jaime Schultz', '0.1'], ['Tanner Scott*', '-0.1'], ['Tayler Scott', '-0.3'], ['Antonio Senzatela', '1.4'], ['Paul Sewald', '0.1'], ['Justin Shafer', '0.2'], ['Bryan Shaw', '1.2'], ['Mike Shawaryn', '-0.3'], ['Justus Sheffield*', '0.0'], ['Jimmie Sherfy', '0.4'], ['Matt Shoemaker', '1.2'], ['JB Shuck*', '0.0'], ['Lucas Sims', '0.1'], ['Tony Sipp*', '0.2'], ['Tyler Skaggs*', '1.0'], ['Devin Smeltzer*', '0.2'], ['Burch Smith', '0.2'], ['Caleb Smith*', '1.5'], ['Josh Smith', '-0.1'], ['Josh Smith*', '0.0'], ['Will Smith*', '1.3'], ['Drew Smyly*', '-0.8'], ['Cy Sneed', '0.0'], ['Blake Snell*', '0.3'], ['Chad Sobotka', '-0.3'], ['Joakim Soria', '0.0'], ['Mike Soroka', '3.0'], ['Gregory Soto*', '-0.4'], ['Glenn Sparkman', '0.2'], ['Jeffrey Springs*', '0.1'], ['Locke St. John*', '0.1'], ['Craig Stammen', '-0.2'], ['Ryne Stanek', '1.0'], ['Max Stassi', '0.0'], ['Drew Steckenrider', '-0.3'], ['Robert Stephenson', '0.3'], ['Brock Stewart', '-0.3'], ['Kohl Stewart', '0.0'], ['Robert Stock', '-0.6'], ['Matt Strahm*', '0.4'], ['Dan Straily', '-1.3'], ['Stephen Strasburg', '2.7'], ['Chris Stratton', '-0.5'], ['Hunter Strickland', '-0.2'], ['Ross Stripling', '0.5'], ['Marcus Stroman', '2.4'], ['Pedro Strop', '0.2'], ['Daniel Stumpf*', '0.0'], ['Andrew Suarez*', '-0.5'], ['Jose Suarez*', '0.1'], ['Ranger Suarez*', '0.0'], ['Jesus Sucre', '0.0'], ['Wander Suero', '0.1'], ['Erik Swanson', '-0.8'], ['Anthony Swarzak', '0.9'], ['Noah Syndergaard', '0.8'], ['Jameson Taillon', '0.2'], ['Masahiro Tanaka', '1.8'], ['Stephen Tarpley*', '-0.4'], ['Josh Taylor*', '-0.1'], ['Julio Teheran', '1.5'], ['Ryan Tepera', '-0.1'], ['Tyler Thornburg', '-0.2'], ['Trent Thornton', '1.3'], ['Lewis Thorpe*', '0.1'], ['Jesus Tinoco', '0.4'], ['Josh Tomlin', '0.5'], ['Carlos Torres', '0.0'], ['Touki Toussaint', '0.0'], ['Blake Treinen', '0.2'], ['Lou Trivino', '-0.6'], ['Nick Tropeano', '-0.2'], ['Spencer Turnbull', '2.2'], ['Jose Urena', '0.0'], ['Julio Urias*', '1.0'], ['Framber Valdez*', '0.1'], ['Phillips Valdez', '0.1'], ['Jason Vargas*', '1.3'], ['Andrew Vasquez*', ''], ['Felipe Vazquez*', '1.7'], ['Vince Velasquez', '0.4'], ['Hector Velazquez', '0.1'], ['Pat Venditte#', '-0.2'], ['Jonny Venters*', '-0.7'], ['Drew VerHagen', '-0.5'], ['Justin Verlander', '3.7'], ['Thyago Vieira', '-0.2'], ['Nick Vincent', '-0.3'], ['Arodys Vizcaino', '0.1'], ['Edinson Volquez', '0.0'], ['Austin Voth', '0.2'], ['Michael Wacha', '-0.3'], ['Jacob Waguespack', '-0.1'], ['Adam Wainwright', '0.9'], ['Marcus Walden', '0.8'], ['Jared Walsh*', '0.1'], ['Wei-Chung Wang*', '0.5'], ['Adam Warren', '-0.3'], ['Tony Watson*', '0.9'], ['Luke Weaver', '1.6'], ['Jacob Webb', '0.8'], ['Tyler Webb*', '0.3'], ['Ryan Weber', '0.1'], ['Allen Webster', '-0.1'], ['J.B. Wendelken', '-0.1'], ['Zack Wheeler', '1.1'], ['Tyler White', '-0.3'], ['Rowan Wick', '0.0'], ['Brad Wieck*', '-0.6'], ['Aaron Wilkerson', '-0.1'], ['Austen Williams', '-0.3'], ['Taylor Williams', '-0.7'], ['Trevor Williams', '1.0'], ['Alex Wilson', '-0.6'], ['Bryse Wilson', '-0.4'], ['Justin Wilson*', '0.0'], ['Trey Wingenter', '0.4'], ['Dan Winkler', '-0.3'], ['Matt Wisler', '-0.1'], ['Nick Wittgren', '0.7'], ['Hunter Wood', '0.3'], ['Brandon Woodruff', '2.1'], ['Brandon Workman', '1.6'], ['Matt Wotherspoon', '-0.4'], ['Kyle Wright', '-0.2'], ['Mike Wright', '-0.6'], ['Steven Wright', '0.1'], ['Jimmy Yacabonis', '0.2'], ['Jordan Yamamoto', '0.9'], ['Ryan Yarbrough*', '0.3'], ['Kirby Yates', '1.8'], ['Gabriel Ynoa', '-0.3'], ['Huascar Ynoa', '0.1'], ['Alex Young*', '0.2'], ['Daniel Zamora*', '0.0'], ['Kyle Zimmer', '-0.1'], ['Jordan Zimmermann', '0.4']]
```

Comment: Wow... that looks intense =) I am a newbie so it will take me some time to learn this code. Thank you so much for your response, sir. I am very grateful!

Comment: @AbleArcher Glad to help!